# How programmatically to export additional .class files with my JAR

Tags: jar, eclipse-plugin, .class-file

I need the .class files (not related to the source files in the project) located in one of the folder inside the project to be exported with JAR too.
If I do export my project with "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" and specify the elements I need to export in **build.properties** file it does export all I need correctly.
Same I want to do programmatically.

When I create the JAR file with

```
final JarPackageData jarPackage = jarCreator.create(project, jarLocation);
```

in create function I set the options like

```
jarPackage.setJarLocation(jarLocation);
jarPackage.setExportClassFiles(true);
jarPackage.setManifestLocation(manifestFile.getFullPath());
jarPackage.setIncludeDirectoryEntries(true);
jarPackage.setExportWarnings(true);
jarPackage.setGenerateManifest(false);
jarPackage.setOverwrite(true);
jarPackage.setElements(elementsToExport.toArray());
```

I did check that all the files I need are in the list **elementsToExport**

```
final IJarExportRunnable jarExport = jarPackage.createJarExportRunnable(owner.getShell());

try{
   owner.getContainer().run(true, true, jarExport);
}
```

The result is:

1. It does export the selected folder to the exported JAR file
2. It does export the text file (for example) located in this folder.
3. **But it does not export the .class files located in this folder.**

Please, let me know if you have any glue how to configure JarPackageData to be able to export what ever is in the selected folder!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the particular build system you are using, but Jar files are zip archives, so if you really need to, you can open them up and insert the extra files yourself. Better yet, write a script to do this.